# Fitch Format Proof, Rules of Inference

Tags: logic

So i have the following fitch problem where I have to cite rules of inference. I have only figured out a number of them listed below. I need help with how this problem uses certain rule of inference as it is confusing to me and I only understand some

$\begin{array}{r|l:l} 1& s \to r\vee p \\[-1ex]
2 & p\to(\neg r\to q)\\[-1ex]
3 & \vert\quad s \\[-1ex]
4 & \vert\quad r\vee p\\[-1ex]
5 & \vert\quad\vert\quad r\\[-1ex]
6 & \vert\quad\vert\quad q\vee r \\[-1ex]
7 & \vert\quad r\to q\vee r\\[-1ex]
8 & \vert\quad\vert\quad \neg r\\[-1ex]
9 & \vert\quad\vert\quad p\\[-1ex]
10 & \vert\quad\vert\quad \neg r\to q\\[-1ex]
11 & \vert\quad\vert\quad q\\[-1ex]
12 & \vert\quad\vert\quad q\vee r\\[-1ex]
13 & \vert\quad \neg r\to q\vee r\\[-1ex]
14 & \vert\quad r\vee\neg r & \star\\[-1ex]
15 & \vert\quad q\vee r\\[-1ex]
16 & s\to q\vee r
\end{array}$

1:  none

2: none

3:  none

4: -> Elimination, 3 and 1

5:none

6: V Introduction, 5

7: -> Introduction, 5 and 6

8: none

9: ??

10: -> Elimination, 9 and 2

11: ??

12: v Introduction , 11

13: ??

14: ??

15: ??

16: V Elimination , cite all steps

Answer (score 0):

$9$ looks like disjunctive syllogism on $4$ and $8$.  Not many Fitch systems have that rule, but apparently this one does.

$11$ is a simple $\rightarrow$ Elim (Modus ponens)

$13$ is like $7$

$14$ is Law of Excluded Middle (introduce any statement of the $p \lor \neg p$ ... no referring statements needed, since that is always true).  Again, many Fitch systems do not have that as a rule, but this one apparently does ...

$15$ is $\lor$ Elim!

But $16$ is again like $7$ and $14$: a simple $\rightarrow$ Intro

OK, so I stated the rules ... can you figure out the line numbers used?

Comment: Our fitch system doesn.t have this, I just checked through all the rules. Is there an alternative to how this could be done?